# Error (1109) Unknown table in MULTI DELETE in 2nd database

Tags: mysql

The following query works when db2 is the connected database.
It also works from db1 on my test server.
On my live server, if the query is run from a connection to db1, I get the (1109) error.

```
DELETE a1,a2
FROM db2.t1 a1, db2.t2 a2
WHERE a1.id=a2.id
AND a1.test=1
```

Is it possible for a server to be configured to stop cross database deletes?

Comment: you are deleting from db2 only!!!!

Comment: Yes, but this is being done (or not) when db1 is the connected db. I am deleting data that is not in the connected db.